# Filtering on unrelated variable in java streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list and I'd like to perform an operation on this list, for example, print the items. But I'd like to do this only if a certain condition applies.

To apply conditions, we have the `.filter` option but it seems like that's only for conditions on the element in the stream itself. (e.g. if item has value `42`)

Let's say my condition is to only proceed if an unrelated random number generated is equal to `42`. How do I do that?

```
items
    .stream()
    .filter( 
       // if randomVar == 42, go ahead)
    .forEach(item -> System.out.println(item));
```

Comment: `filter(x -> randomVar == 42)` works perfectly fine.

Comment: Why not wrap the stream operation in a simple `if` condition? `if (randomValue == 42) { items.stream().forEach(item -> System.out.println(item));}`

Comment: Once again a top Google question is punished by people who didn't come here looking for answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A one possible solution is to define a custom predicate like this:

`Predicate<Item> myPredicate = item -> randomVar == 42;`

Then you can use the predicate in your stream:

```
items
    .stream()
    .filter(myPredicate)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```